# Finding out SIM card operator

Tags: java, at-command, javax.comm, sim-card

My JAVA program can find a modem connected with serial port. Like:

```
COM1: Serial
COM3: Serial  // This is my modem
LPT1: Parallel
LPT2: Parallel
```

Is there any AT Command or other process which can help me to find out the operators identity (name), who's SIM is being used in the modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for finding out which network you are registered on is

```
AT+COPS?
```

On mine, that outputs

```
+COPS: 0,0,"giffgaff",2
```

Where the string in the quotes is the operator's name.